# Trying to implement shopping cart using riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I'm trying to build remote shopping cart "I will add CRUD requests later" For now I'm just trying to build it using Riverpod NotifierProvider in the first stage.

I can fill my cart successfully However, I'm facing this error while displaying my items on the cart page.

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
> The following _CastError was thrown building:
> Null check operator used on a null value

here is my cart screen page:

```
class CartPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CartPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final state = ref.watch(cartRepositoryProvider);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Cart"),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: state.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                          title: Text(state.values.toList()[index].itemsName!),
                          // id: state.values.toList()[index].`!,
                          // itemsName: state.values.toList()[index].itemsName!,
                          // price: state.values.toList()[index].price!,
                          // qty: state.values.toList()[index].qty!,
                          // image: state.values.toList()[index].image!,
                        )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

also here is my cart_controller where I'm modifying the state based on my conditions.

```
class CartRepository extends Notifier<Map<String, CartItem>> {
  @override
  Map<String, CartItem> build() {
    return {};
  }

  void addItem({required String productId, price, title, name, image}) {
    if (state.containsKey(productId)) {
      state.update(
          productId,
          (value) => CartItem(
              productId: value.productId,
              itemsName: value.itemsName,
              price: value.price,
              image: value.image,
              qty: value.qty! + 1));
    }
    if (!state.containsKey(productId)) {
      // cart.addAll({item.productId: item});
      state.putIfAbsent(
        productId,
        () => CartItem(
            productId: productId,
            itemsName: title,
            price: price,
            image: image,
            // productId: item.productId,
            qty: 0),
      );
    }
  }

  void removeItem(String id) {
    if (state.containsKey(id)) {
      state.update(
          id,
          (value) => CartItem(
              itemsName: value.itemsName,
              price: value.price,
              image: value.image,
              productId: value.productId,
              qty: value.qty! - 1));
    }
  }

  void clearCart() {
    state.clear();
  }

  getCartItem<String>(id) {
    if (state.containsKey(id)) {
      int quantity = state[id]!.qty ?? 0;
      return quantity;
    }
  }
}

final cartRepositoryProvider =
    NotifierProvider<CartRepository, Map<String, CartItem>>(CartRepository.new);
```

Furthermore, here is my **cartItem Model**:

```
import 'package:ecommerceriverpod/src/features/cart/domain/item.dart';
import 'package:ecommerceriverpod/src/features/products/domain/product.dart';

class CartItem {
  String? productId;
  String? itemsName;
  String? price;
  String? image;
  int? qty;

  CartItem({
    required this.productId,
    required this.itemsName,
    required this.price,
    required this.image,
    required this.qty,
  });
}
```

I'm sure it contains many mistakes but solving it will be highly appreciated.
Also, I couldn't add the product_screen because of more code but I think this is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accessing a `CartItem` that does not exist

```dart
title: Text(state.values.toList()[index].itemsName!),
```

because the list will be empty at this point:

```dart
/// CartRepository
@override
Map<String, CartItem> build() {
  return {};
}
```

Process the empty list in your widget:

```dart
if (state.isEmpty) return Text('Not found Cards');
```

Next, you must be very sure that your `itemsName` field is not null. Either get rid of nullable fields in the `CartItem` model, or handle each nullable field in your ui accordingly:

```dart
final item = state.values.toList()[index]!;
final itemName = item.itemsName ?? '';

title: Text(itemName),
```